# Run uploaded notebook through html upload

Tags: web

my professor gave me the following task:

make a web page, that contains a form with a single file upload field. when the user uploads the file, then, using the webserver of choice (in my case - apache + php on windows), execute the script and return results to the user via the same webpage where he uploaded the script. in case there is some input data, prompt the user to enter it.

i don't know where to start on this, the upload handling is quite easy(using javascript, html and php as backend), but after that i dont know how to run it, hot to make the user enter input data if needed etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to Mathematica or the Wolfram Language.

Comment: i am not asking for upload script, i am asking about script execution and processing. i think is pretty much clear what i am asking

Comment: It is not at all clear what relationship this question has to [Mathematica](http://wri.com). If it is indeed related, please explain to avoid the question being closed.

Comment: here is the relationship: i call mathematica through cli, by calling: `math.exe -script <path_to_notebook.nb>` but i do not get any output back, so that is one issue i am facing. if i can get the output (from a plot for example) then i can return that to the user.

Comment: You need to rewrite the question and focus on the Mathematica aspect. Right now it sounds like you have trouble building a website with PHP and HTML.

Comment: i know how to build website with php and html, the problem rises when i get no output when calling the script through cli like: `math.exe -script <path_to_notebook.com`